# How to organize a long SQL statement written in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb

I've written a microservice that is doing external calls to a SQL database. I have a js file that is solely dedicated to these awful looking queries that are formed as a string..

```
let data_example = 'SELECT * \
WHERE BLAH = BLAH AND \
....';
```

It's barely human readable and looks awful. What's the best way to store/organize or approach a long SQL query string that needs to be stored and called in Node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. You could store them in a file you read at program startup, so you're authoring them in a tool that understands SQL, perhaps can even connect to your DB to auto-complete things for you, can help you format, do syntax highlighting, etc.
2. You can use ES2015 ("ES6") [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (also called "template literals"):

   ```
   let data_example = `
       SELECT *
       WHERE BLAH = BLAH AND ...
   `;
   ```

   Template strings can span lines (note that newlines, and whitespace at the beginning of subsequent lines, *are* part of the string).

   Just be sure you don't use the features of template strings to fill in parameters through (hidden) string concatenation, because [That Would Be Wrong™](http://bobby-tables.com/). :-) That is, just like you wouldn't do this:

   ```
   // We know NOT to do this
   example = "WHERE SomeColumn = '" + userInputValue + "'";
   ```

   don't do the same thing using the hidden string concatenation of template strings:

   ```
   // We also know NOT to do this
   example = `WHERE SomeColumn = ${userInputValue};`
   ```

   ....which is how you would do that string concatenation using a template string. If you're in the habit of using template strings, it would be really easy to do that by mistake, and have an SQL Injection vector.

There are probably use cases for both options.

Comment: Do you mean don't do something like 'hello = "' + VAR_NAME + '" ?

Comment: its **`** not **'**

Comment: actually i was referring to @coderkid comment:  'hello = "' + VAR_NAME + '"

Comment: Ok, you are referring to SQL injection here, other wise one can use this ``WHERE SomeColumn = ${userInputValue};``

Comment: @Nivesh Yeah, the point is you'd never do that, because [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). :-)

Comment: Curious, as I am doing what you commented in the answer. How would I then substitute strings into the query?

Comment: @coderkid: You want to be using whatever your DB layer calls "prepared statements" and passing any value that isn't absolutely **guaranteed** to be from your own code in as a parameter, not using string concat. Point me at what you're using in Node (there are a couple of different DB layers) and I'll be happy to look at its docs and point to the right thing.

Comment: Awesome. Well I am using the MariaDB module

Comment: @coderkid: The examples on [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariasql) show how to do it, you use placeholders (like `:name`) and pass in an object with matching properties (`{name: "foo"}`), e.g. `c.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id AND name = :name', { id: 1337, name: 'Frylock' }...` The `:id` and `:name` are parameter placeholders, their values are supplied in the object.

Comment: @coderkid: Just to close the loop: And then the driver you're using ensures that those parameters are handled correctly to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115240/discussion-between-coderkid-and-t-j-crowder).